# Trying to return the first column value in my listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to return the first column in my list view `DriverListView`:

[image]

but all I get is:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
    private void DriverListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DriverListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        MessageBox.Show(DriverListView.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
    }
```

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="DriverListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="627" Margin="15,13,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="577" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="DriverListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Driver" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DNo}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Paid Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PDate}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Rent Paid" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PRent}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="125" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

What could be going wrong? It appears to be returning the object instead of the text value, which is incorrect.

Comment: Have you overridden the `ToString` method? (`SelectedItems` is supposed to return a list of objects)

Comment: Is `DriverListView` a `ListView` or a custom class that inherits from `ListView`? If it's a plain `ListView` [`ListViewItem.ToString`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListViewItem.cs) should return something like: `"ListViewItem: {18}"`

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is a `ListView`

Comment: @Sayse I have not overwritten it

Comment: @methuselah:  If it's a plain `ListView` [`ListViewItem.ToString`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListViewItem.cs) should return something like: `"ListViewItem: {18}"` and `ListViewItem.Text` should return: `18`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I may be wrong, I have updated the question to include information about the ListView item.

Comment: @methuselah: i thought that it was `winforms`. You should add the `WPF`-tag. The difference it that in winforms `SelectedItems` is a `SelectedListViewItemCollection` whereas in WPF it's just an object-collection.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok thanks. Just updated it I've looked at the response by user3231903 but don't understand what I need to do next. I have already defined a class with one property per column. How do I then take it forward? - http://pastebin.com/b8bne6Ja

Comment: Why don't you have something like `string item = DriverListView.Items[DriverListView.FocusedItem.Index].Text;`

Comment: @Izzy - I get the following error `Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'FocusedItem' and no extension method 'FocusedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MainWindow.xaml.cs 78 63 SpeedyRent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your DriverListView is a class that inherits from ListView.
ListView.Items accepts objects to store. So if you use DriverListView.SelectedItems[0] you get the first selected row in your ListView. Try to cast it to the correct type.

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string MyProperty2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyClass(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
        MyProperty1 = prop1;
        MyProperty2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

I assume that you have added objects of MyClass to your DriversListView

```
DriversListView.Items.Add(new MyClass("hello", "world"));
```

So your DriverListView contains multiple objects of the class MyClass. The selected one is stored in the first item of DriverListView.SelectedItems Collection.
So you can cast it to MyClass to read the properties.

```
MyClass selectedItem = (MyClass)DriverListView.SelectedItems[0];
```

now you can work with

```
selectedItem.MyProperty1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really understand how this would fit into the context of my code. I have already defined a class with one property per column. What next? - http://pastebin.com/b8bne6Ja

Comment: Try the following:
`DriverItemList selectedItem = (DriverItemList )DriverListView.SelectedItems[0];`
Now access the properties by using `selectedItem.DNo`

Comment: The name of the class is `DbConnect`. I've just tested the code `var selectedItem = (DbConnect)DriverListView.SelectedItems[0];` and get the following error message `Unable to cast object of type 'DriverItemList' to type 'SpeedyRent.DbConnect'`

Comment: No Problem. Could you mark my answer as right? Cause I was just trying to explain it to you in details. But in this case I confused you ;) Have a nice day